# Solr configuration to filter all docs with titles that exactly match the search query itself

Tags: xml, search, solr, configuration

I'm trying to setup a solr configuration to filter out all the docs with titles that exactly match the search query string itself. So far I've got this:

```
<requestHandler name="my_search" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="defType">my_search</str>
  <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
</lst>
<lst name="appends">
  <str name="fq">{!frange l=0.1 u=1000}score</str>
</lst>
```

So essentially if I had a bunch of docs with titles like so:

```
"blue box on a road"
"road box with blue tail"
"box with blue road"
```

and I searched for "box with blue road", given my configuration, all three docs would return, but once I add the extra filter, the doc with the title "box with blue road" would not return. I thought if I added this line to the appends section, I'd be able to achieve what I'm trying to do:

```
<str name="fq">-title_en:$q</str>
```

But alas, I think the syntax is wrong (specifically the $q part) as I'm not getting the desired result. My question is, is this even possible, and if so, what is the right syntax to refer to the query string in the xml config.

fyi, I'm doing this is part of a larger negative query targeting project and this would just be part of the prototyping.

Would appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue as you say is the $q part. This

```
<str name="fq">-title_en:"box with blue road"</str>
```

does work in a Solr4.X at least. But not sure if the parameter substitution can be used for what you want...before 5.1 (just released a day or two ago).

In 5.1 you can do it for sure, check [Parameter Substitution / Macro Expansion](http://yonik.com/solr-query-parameter-substitution/), your query would be written like this:

```
q=${querytext}
&fq={!frange l=0.1 u=1000}score
&fq=-title_en:${querytext}
&querytext="box with blue road"
```

Comment: I'm not using 5.1 so this won't work for me but thank you for sharing the info. I did find another way of doing what I'm trying to do: by writing a QParserPlugin in java that intercepts the query and adds the fq parameter to the request.